# Window.open of JavaScript is acting before it gets to the Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails controller I have something like this:

```
def index
  provider_id = params[:provider] ||= 'all'
  thera_class = params[:therapeutic_class] ||= 'all'
  med_name = params[:medication_name] ||= 'all'
```

In the JavaScript side I am passing these params as URL query params so when it gets called it goes to this Index action method:

```
window.open("http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?provider="+provider_id+"&"+"therapeutic_class="+thera_class+"&"+"medication_name="+medication_name);
```

The problem is the JavaScript values I am passing if they don't have a value and are undefined they will be passed as undefined.

I am more concerned to know is it too much architecturally wrong that I am doing this? What is the "Rails way" of doing it? Specially the routing from Javascript to Rails controller and passing params to it is where I need your architectural input.

Comment: Try something like: `provider="+provider_id || ''+"&"+"therapeutic` but i think you will still get the `params[:provider]` which would be empty string...

Comment: Did my answer help? Or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch your infos on the Client side with Javascript, I guess you initialize the variables provider_id, therapeutic_class, etc. Something like this:

```
var provider_id = $('#provider').val();
var thera_class = $('#therapeutic_class').val();
# etc.
# and then you do:
window.open("http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?provider="+provider_id+"&"+"therapeutic_class="+thera_class+"&"+"medication_name="+medication_name);
```

If yes, I would suggest you to do so:

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?";
var params = { };
var params_names = [ 'provider', 'therapeutic_class', 'medication_name' ];
$.each(params_names, function(i, param_name) {
  var value = $('#'+param_name).val();
  if(value !== undefined && value != '') {
    params[param_name] = value;
  }
})
$.each(params, function(key, value) {
  url += key + "=" + value + "&";
})
window.open(url)
```

Comment: hmm yep not as beautiful as you did it in the JS side but I almost did the same to cover up that issue with wring some if-else and checking if the value is undefined I changed them to be 'all' But my question is more of to know what is the better way? I am sure there should be a better way to make Javascript route to that controller and there should be a better way for JS to pass variables to controller...I am looking for those.

Comment: Take a look at Backbone & Angular (for Single Page Apps), it makes routes on the client side